# c.BindJSON with optional parameters

Tags: rest, go

I am using go-gin and trying to implement a PATCH API. 3 fields are editable so I have a struct defined like this

```
type Person struct {
    Name         string  `form:"name" json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Account      string  `form:"account" json:"account" binding:"required"`
    PrimaryOwner string  `form:"primary_owner" json:"primary_owner" binding:"required"`
}
```

I am trying to bind json like this:

```
var json Person
if c.BindJSON(&json) == nil {
        fmt.Println("json matched!!!!!!!")
    }else {
        fmt.Println("json not matched!!!!!!!")
}
```

Problem is it tries to bind all the parameters. If I give all parameters it gets matched but even if one parameter is missing it goes in else block. In patch API I don't want compulsary binding. If I remove `binding:"required"` from all fields it always matches, even if I give some key like `sdfsdfsdf`. How can make binding to all parameters but not all together. The keys in json request body should be verified but all keys should not be required at the same time.

Comment: Same issue for me. I think major thing is that binding/validation is coupled with a model. Better option could be to have it done per route, but with gin it's not easily possible.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Just found that question unanswered.

So you want to bind all parameters and minimal one is required

> How can make binding to all parameters but not all together.

You almost answered your question here:

> If I remove binding:"required" from all fields it always matches

So I would remove the required and check every value.

```
var json Person
if err := c.BindJSON(&json); err != nil {
        // error handling here
        // something went wrong
    }
    if json.Name == "" && json.Account == "" && json.PrimaryOwner  == "" {
        // no key is given... 
    }
}
```